# Change image color without CSS filter

Tags: html, css

I would like to change the color of an image with CSS.

The problem is that it cannot be with filters, I usually use this code:

```
filter: hue-rotate(339deg) brightness(1);
```

It works, but if the image is black for example it does not work, and if it has colors it only shows variations of X color. I would like to be able to change all the colors.

Comment: is the image an SVG?

Comment: The image is PNG. Why?

Comment: @PrincipeMestizo What are you trying to do?

Comment: I wanna this: https://webdevtrick.com/demos/css-filter-editor/ But... that instead of having so many filters it has only one to change the color.

Comment: The only thing I want is to be able to change all the colors. Example: if the image is black, I want to put it red, blue, yellow, or any other color.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a color filter on an image by:

- positioning a layer with a partially transparent background (with the use of [`rgba()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/rgba()))

Demo:

```js
const layer = document.querySelector('.layer');
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  const r = parseInt(input.value.substr(1, 2), 16)
  const g = parseInt(input.value.substr(3, 2), 16)
  const b = parseInt(input.value.substr(5, 2), 16)
  layer.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, 0.9)`;
})
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width:fit-content;
}

.layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/0etSSYl.png");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="layer"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>

<hr>
<input type="color" id="input">
<-- apply color filter
```

Comment: I have an <img src="... it's possible with that?

Comment: @PrincipeMestizo You would have to make it black & white, which is not possible without using CSS filter.

Comment: @PrincipeMestizo It looks slightly confusing, but really it's just simple string manipulation that's specific to this scenario. Since input `type="color"` returns the value in hex, we have to extract the RGB values to make the background partially transparent since hex doesn't support partially transparent colors.

Comment: This method does not work for me, because the entire image is filled, even the transparent part.